# MASM32 - set a string value on a single line, esi not correctly set, access violation

Tags: string, assembly, masm32

I am trying to use rep movsb to set a string to a variable.  The rep movsb throws an access violation because my mov esi, offset ‘Dog’ is not pointing to the correct memory address.  I am including the code and the only thing I can think of is that it might have something to do with the segments.  I have a paid attention to the segment registers in the debugger, but I am afraid I do know exactly how to work the problem if the problem is in fact segment registers.  Other than that I don’t know, I just know that esi is not being set correctly, but am unsure why.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include windows.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

addElement PROTO: ptr DbRecord
readArray PROTO
stringLength PROTO : ptr dword

.data?
    DbRecord struct
        Id      dd  ?
        WordOne     db 32   dup(?) ; db is define byte, set value of byte
        WordTwo     db 32   dup(?)
        WordThree   db 32   dup(?)
        Year        dd  ?
    DbRecord ends

    array dword 512 dup(?)      ; pointer in memory to start of array
;   newElementPointer DbRecord <>
    hStdOut dd ?
    bytesWritten dd ?

.data
    arrayCount dd 0
    hello db 'Hello World!', 0

.code
main proc
    LOCAL DbRecord01:DbRecord
    LOCAL DbRecord02:DbRecord
    mov [DbRecord01.Id], 1;

    ; any other way than one character at a time?
    ;mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne], 'D'
    ;mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 1], 'o'
    ;mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 2], 'g'
    ;mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 3], 0

    lea edi, DbRecord01.WordOne
    mov esi, offset 'Dog'   ; esi is not set correctly, inspection of memory does not show 'Dog'
    mov ecx, 3
    rep movsb

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo], 'C'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 1], 'a'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 2], 't'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 3], 0

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree], 'E'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 1], 'y'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 2], 'e'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 3], 0
    mov [DbRecord01.Year], 2022;

    mov [DbRecord02.Id], 2;

    ; any other way than one character at a time?
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordOne], 'C'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordOne + 1], 'a'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordOne + 2], 'r'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordOne + 3], 0

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordTwo], 'H'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordTwo + 1], 'o'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordTwo + 2], 'u'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordTwo + 3], 's'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordTwo + 4], 'e'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordTwo + 5], 0

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree], 'W'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree + 1], 'i'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree + 2], 'n'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree + 3], 'd'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree + 4], 'o'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree + 5], 'w'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree + 6], 's'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord02.WordThree + 7], 0

    mov [DbRecord02.Year], 2002;
        
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov [hStdOut], eax

    invoke WriteConsole, hStdOut, offset hello, sizeof hello, offset bytesWritten, NULL
    invoke addElement, addr DbRecord01
    invoke addElement, addr DbRecord02
    invoke readArray

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
    ret
main endp

addElement proc uses edx DbRecordPointer: ptr DbRecord
    Local newElementPointer: Dword
    invoke VirtualAlloc, NULL, sizeof DbRecord, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE
    mov newElementPointer, eax
    invoke RtlMoveMemory, eax , DbRecordPointer, sizeof DbRecord
    mov edx, arrayCount
    mov dword ptr  [array +4*edx], eax
    inc edx
    mov arrayCount, edx

    ret
addElement endp

readArray proc uses ebx
    xor ebx, ebx
    .while ebx < arrayCount
        mov eax, [array+4*ebx]
        lea eax, [eax+offset DbRecord.WordOne]
        invoke stringLength, eax
        mov edx, eax
        mov eax, [array+4*ebx]
        lea eax, [eax+offset DbRecord.WordOne]

        invoke WriteConsole, hStdOut, eax, edx, offset bytesWritten, NULL

        mov eax, [array+4*ebx]
        lea eax, [eax+offset DbRecord.WordTwo]
        invoke stringLength, eax
        mov edx, eax
        mov eax, [array+4*ebx]
        lea eax, [eax+offset DbRecord.WordTwo]

        invoke WriteConsole, hStdOut, eax, edx, offset bytesWritten, NULL

        mov eax, [array+4*ebx]
        lea eax, [eax+offset DbRecord.WordThree]
        invoke stringLength, eax
        mov edx, eax
        mov eax, [array+4*ebx]
        lea eax, [eax+offset DbRecord.WordThree]

        invoke WriteConsole, hStdOut, eax, edx, offset bytesWritten, NULL

        inc ebx
    .endw
    ret
readArray endp

stringLength proc uses ecx stringPtr: ptr dword

    ; find length of string
    mov edi, stringPtr
    mov ecx, -1
    mov al, 0
    repne scasb
    not ecx

    mov eax, ecx
    ret

stringLength endp

end main
```

Comment: `offset 'Dog'` does not do what you want. You need to define that in memory for it to have an address for `movs`. You could just use a `mov` instead.

Comment: Does that mean I need to put something in .data or .data?  The whole point is that I don’t want a ton of stuff in .data or .data?  I mean it is using mov, but I thought it had to have the address of ‘Dog’ in esi?  So if I can do that without using a .data or .data?

Comment: I see online that offset is for .data only, I guess that makes sense, I just wanted to do everything on one line.

Comment: @jester I guess I could have a single string global to act as a buffer for all my various strings.

Comment: This is all static data there is no reason to create them from code. Just initialize two records in data section and then pass their address to the `addElement`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is all learning for me, I am going to make some changes, maybe ReadConsole rather than static data.  Trying to think of things I don't yet understand.  You've been a big help.

Comment: Since it's a 4 character string you could pass its ascii equivalent in a register as a number, e.g. `mov esi, 0x446F6700`